# Store a screen capture (Bitblt) in a memory buffer to send over IdTCPClient

Tags: graphics, tcp, c++builder, indy, c++builder-6

In c++ builder 6 on windows vista ...

```
Graphics:: TBitmap * bmpscreencapture = new Graphics::TBitmap;
bmpscreencapture-> Height = Screen-> Height;
bmpscreencapture-> Width = Screen-> Width;
HDC ScreenSrc = GetWindowDC (0);
BitBlt (bmpscreencapture-> Canvas-> Handle, 0, 0, Screen-> Width,
Screen-> Height, ScreenSrc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
Canvas->Draw(10, 10, bmpscreencapture);
ReleaseDC (GetDesktopWindow (), ScreenSrc);
delete bmpscreencapture;
```

I currently have a section of code for capturing the screen and displaying the screen capture onto an empty form.  What I would like to do is store the captured image into a memory buffer and then send this buffer over the internet using the indy client IdTCPClient to be received by a similar program using indy server IDTCPServer.

Has anyone got any suggestions/ideas of how to accomplish this?? I am fairly new to graphics programming

Answer (score 2):

Use the TBitmap::SaveToStream() method to save the data to a TStream, such as a TMemoryStream.  Then pass the TStream to Indy's TIdTCPConnection::WriteStream() (Indy 9 and earlier) or TIdIOHandler::Write(TStream) (Indy 10) method.  On the recieving end, you can then use the TIdTCPConnection/TIdIOHandler::ReadStream() method to read the data into a TStream, and then pass the TStream to the TBitmap::LoadFromStream() method.