# Create DirectShow Filter to Select HWND

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, filter, directshow, directshow.net

How to create a DirectShow Filter and the main concern is how to select the window to follow.
I want to do something like google plus hangout uses to select the window to show in screen share.

Thanks to help :)

Comment: Would you like to output video through `DirectShow` to selected windows?

Comment: I want to capture the selected window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need DirectShow to capture window image. With a DC-to-DC `BitBlt` the picture is already yours. See:

- [Writing to the screen from the screen using BitBlt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052130/writing-to-the-screen-from-the-screen-using-bitblt)
- [How to speed up BitBlt to capture screen with aero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044154/how-to-speed-up-bitblt-to-capture-screen-with-aero)
- [Store a screen capture (Bitblt) in a memory buffer to send over IdTCPClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256605/store-a-screen-capture-bitblt-in-a-memory-buffer-to-send-over-idtcpclient)

If you want to wrap this into a DirectShow filter, Windows SDK sample [Push Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is doing a close thing (`CPushSourceDesktop`).

Comment: thanks a lot for the links i will study them but how to lock a window by the hwnd ? 
can you help me ?

Comment: What do you mean "lock"? If you have `HWND` then you can get its device context using `GetDC` or `GetWindowDC` and copy from there.

Comment: I been working with what @Roman says and i modified this [project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22121737/CaptureScreen.rar) but now i want to use this as a directshow filter to capture as a video. how can i do this?